# Best way to re-populate input field with Model data on front-end?

Tags: templating, form, conditional

I have a Plugin which saves data from a form the user enters on my front-end. When the input data is wrong and I display my validation errors using *getErrors* from the Model I want to re-populate all my form fields with the submitted data in my Twig template.

Right now I'm doing this like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldName" value="{% if model is defined %}{{ model.fieldName}}{% endif %}"/>
```

Is this the correct way of doing this or is there a better practice?

Seems like there's to many unnecessary *if* statements going on...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the Craft docs do it is basically how you are already:

```
<label for="userLastName">Last Name *</label>
<input id="userLastName" type="text" name="fields[userLastName]" {%- if entry is defined %} value="{{ entry.userLastName }}"{% endif -%}>
```

Comment: Cool. Then I guess this is the way to go forward. Cheers! :)

Comment: Worth noting... You can also use Twig's [ternary syntax](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators): `{{- entry is defined ? 'value="'~entry.userLastName~'"' -}}`

Answer (score 0):

If you use that form to edit entries AND add new ones, then yes, this is probably the correct way to do this. But if this is an edit only form / template then you could check for the model once and if no `model is defined` don't show your form at all.

```
{% if model is defined %}
    <input type="text" name="fieldName" value="{{ model.fieldName}}"/>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is for a regular form the user submits info with and if the validation fails the user is promted with having to correct it's data before re-submitting.

Comment: No. Then using it inline within your input fields is correct, @naboo!